# The `brew cleanup` command does not remove an old mysql directory

Tags: homebrew

When I execute `brew outdated` I get the following among many things

- `mysql (5.7.21, 5.7.22) < 8.0.17_1` two old versions

After to do `brew cleanup` expecting to remove `5.7.21` (because is old) appears among many things:

- `Warning: Skipping mysql: most recent version 8.0.17_1 not installed`

Even with the previous execution, the `5.7.21` remains. I had expected to see deleted the former and keep the latter at least

If I execute `brew info mysql` I got:

```
mysql: stable 8.0.17
Open source relational database management system
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/
Conflicts with:
  mariadb (because mysql, mariadb, and percona install the same binaries.)
  mariadb-connector-c (because both install plugins)
  mysql-connector-c (because both install MySQL client libraries)
  percona-server (because mysql, mariadb, and percona install the same binaries.)
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21 (323 files, 235.0MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-01-30 at 11:34:27
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22 (317 files, 235MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-04-19 at 13:34:21
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mysql.rb
...
```

My Mac is old, I can't upgrade `Homebrew` and therefore not possible upgrade `MySQL` to `8.0.17_1`.

Anyway, how I can remove without any problem `5.7.21` and keep `5.7.22` which is higher?.

I am not sure if delete manually the `5.7.21` directory in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql` is safe. I want keep all in a consistent state.

What is the correct approach to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: remove the installation folder directly. It's totally safe.

`brew cleanup` requires the latest version to be installed. This is reported in [issue 412](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/412). But not any improvement has been done.

What is the reason behind disallowing the cleanup of older versions of formulas when the most recent is not installed?

> Technically, Homebrew doesn't consider a formula to be installed unless the latest version it knows of is installed. And because only installed formulae (in the sense I explained here) are checked for older versions that could be cleaned up, this isn't happening.